# updateItem with DynamoDb in PHP (StringSet)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDb in PHP, but I cant update my items (string set).

```
$friends_list = array();
array_push( $friends_list, "user1" );

$response = $client->updateItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'myTable',
    'Key' => array(
        'id' => array(Type::STRING => $userid),
        'username' => array(Type::STRING => $username)
    ),
    'AttributeUpdates' => array(
        'friends_list' => array(
            'Value' => array(Type::STRING_SET => $friends_list),
            'Action' => AttributeAction::PUT)
    ),
    'ReturnValues' => 'ALL_NEW'
));
```

I get a error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException: AWS Error Code: SerializationException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: EG1EUDVTNPRST9DAA94NQP592BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: class java.lang.Short can not be converted to an String, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.5 Guzzle/3.9.2 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
thrown in /var/www/html/aws-sdk-php-master/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91
```

Why?

$friends_list is array, but can't update with StringSet.

this code is no error :

```
'Value' => array(Type::STRING_SET => array("user1")),
```

but, this code get a error message :

```
'Value' => array(Type::STRING_SET => $friends_list),
```

I can't understand.

Comment: If `$userid` is an integer, you'll need to cast it to a string.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But $userid is string. $userid = 'user1';

Comment: If you can [show a wire log](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-see-what-data-is-sent-over-the-wire) of the request, it should be easy for me to see what the problem is. (Note: make sure to remove any sensitive info like access key and signature values from the wire log before posting).